# Functors and iteration trough vector

Tags: c++, lambda, functor

I'm trying to get into 'modern' C++, so I'm trying to learn how to properly use functors, and, subsequently, lambdas.
I think I've understood basic principle behind it, but I'm having trouble to understand how to acquire any element from a vector that is passed to my algorithm.
So, let's say I wish to create a Fibonacci sequence of length N...

```
struct Adder {
    int operator()(int a, int b) {return a+b;}
};
const int N = 10;

int main() {

    std::vector<int> vec = {0, 1};
    vec.resize(N);

    //Old Way
    for(int i = 2; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        vec[i] = vec[i-1] + vec[i-2];
    }

    std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), [](int i){return i*3;});    //single operator given to function, works

//    std::transform(vec.begin()+2, vec.end(), vec.begin(), /*here two calls are needed , for a and b operators*/);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically my question is how to activate functor defined in `struct Adder`? What is the proper way to pass two operators to him?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?  Transform two sequences to one sequence?

Comment: @L.F. I wish to get the same effect as in `for loop` above. Non-commented call to `std::transform` is a simple demonstration of how its possible to retrieve current iterator position. What I'm interested in is how to retrieve any element that is not `vec[i]`, but is `vec[i+a]` where `a` can be both positive and negative value (with obvious out-of-bounds restrictions etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Adder::operator()` should be `const`.  And your `Adder` functor is unnecessary.  Just use `std::plus<>`.

Since C++17, we have the `transform` overload that accepts two sequences.  So we can do: (you can use `Adder{}` in place of `std::plus<>{}` if you want)

```
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end() - 2, vec.begin() + 1, vec.begin() + 2, std::plus<>{});
```

Minimal example: ([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zVtCDhb3eK5DbvBq))

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

constexpr int N = 10;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{0, 1};
    vec.resize(N);

    std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end() - 2, vec.begin() + 1, vec.begin() + 2, std::plus<>{});

    for (int x : vec)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```